# ASP MVC TempData value in partial view error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have the following constants defined as follows:

```
namespace MyProject.Constants
{
  public static class AppConstants
  {
    // View Bag / Temp Data Constants
    public const string CurrentAction = "CurrentAction";
    public const string CurrentController = "CurrentController";

  }
}
```

In my _layout.cshtml file I am setting them as follows:

```
@using MyProject.Constants
@{
    TempData[AppConstants.CurrentAction] = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action").ToLower();
    TempData[AppConstants.CurrentController] = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller").ToLower();
 }
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    ...
    <body>

      @Html.Partial("_SubNavigation")

    </body>
  </html>
```

But I'm unable to access the TempData inside my _SubNavigation.cshtml partial view:

```
 <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="@(TempData[AppConstants.CurrentController].ToString() == "home" && TempData[AppConstants.CurrentAction].ToString() == "index" ? "active" : "")">Home</a></li>
```

I get error `The name 'AppConstants' does not exist in the current context`

If I add the following snippet directly inside the partial then it works?

```
@using MyProject.Constants
@{
    TempData[AppConstants.CurrentAction] = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action").ToLower();
    TempData[AppConstants.CurrentController] = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller").ToLower();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get error The name 'AppConstants' does not exist in the current context

Without the snippet you quote, does you partial view start with

```
@using MyProject.Constants
```

?

This is needed in every view that references names in that namespace, and for any other namespaces you need. If you need a namespace is a significant proportion of your views consider adding it to the global namespaces list in the `web.config` file in the Views folder.

Comment: no the partial view doesn't start with `@using MyProject.Constants` do I need to include it?

Comment: Is there a way I can include these constants without having to define  @using in every single partial view? I want to define once in the _layout.cshtml only.

Comment: @ozzii You can define global usings in the `web.config` in the views folder. (You'll see `System.Web.Mvc` and a few other namespaces are included by default.)